# My wordpress site's performance is not improving with W3TotalCache plugin. Why?

Tags: wordpress, performance, w3-total-cache

My site is hosted on Hostgator and I am using Eleven40 theme from for my site beside that I am using W3TotalCache plugin to improve my site's performance. But the performance is still not improving. In gtmetrix it's showing very low performance. **GZip compression enabled**, **images are compressed** but still not getting expected result. Not only these two but from many other aspects like page size, load speed, the number of requests etc it's lagging.

Can anyone please suggest me a way around?

[GTmetrix report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiVNl.jpg)

Comment: did you just install and enable the plugin or you have set it up by changing settings and configuration ?

Comment: Actually previously I had this plugin w3totalcache installed but due to some inconsistencies I had uninstalled it completely. But at that time performance rating was great in GTmetrix. But in the 2nd time when I installed & configured the plugin.... performance is not at all increasing

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin - it has worked for me a few times in the past:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/